# Update multiple rows with one query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I found something that works with updating one field at here: http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/articles/sql/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/

```
UPDATE person
    SET name = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Jim'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Mike'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Precious'
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

My question is how to update more than one field? Such as:

```
UPDATE person
    SET name = CASE, sex = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Jim', 'female'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Mike', 'male'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Precious', 'male'
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Which doesn't work of course. Tried a few other combination and failed. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
UPDATE person
    SET name = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Jim'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Mike'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Precious'
    END,
    sex = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'female'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'male'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'male'
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried something like below. You can have multiple "SET" statements one for each column.

```
UPDATE person 
    SET name = CASE id 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Jim' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Mike' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Precious' 
    END, 
    sex = CASE id 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'female' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'male' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'male' 
    END 
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```