# Update multiple rows with different, optional values for different colums

Tags: sql, mysql

This is basically an extension of [Update multiple rows with one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528181/update-multiple-rows-with-one-query).  I want to be able to update multiple columns of multiple rows at a time, but not necessarily to update every column of every row.

Here is an example command I would like to be able to execute:

```
UPDATE person
SET name = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Jim'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Precious'
END,
sex = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'female'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'male'
END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

However this returns an error, telling me column 'name' cannot be null.  So it seem to me that specifying `WHERE id IN (x,y,z)` means all selected columns must be updated, even though we're indicating which values to place on a case by case basis.

Is there any way around this limitation, like a special notation to indicate "keep the original value"?  If not, is there some other way to update select, arbitrary columns of multiple rows in one query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would need to add an `Else` updating it to its original value.

```
UPDATE person
SET name = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Jim'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Precious'
    ELSE name
END,
sex = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'female'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'male'
    ELSE sex
END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
...
SET name = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Jim'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Precious'
    ELSE name -- defaulting to the value it already has.
...
```