# Best way to UPDATE multiple rows in oracle database using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, model-view-controller

I have a variable list of IDs. I want to update the "Status" column for each of those IDs in an Oracle database. I've searched and have come across the following options:

- OracleDataAdapter - Don't have a DataTable, only IDs
- for loop which contains UPDATE statement (could be thousands of UPDATEs)
- Stored Procedure - Hoping not to have to do this

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: no need to be so against stored procedures, those are not so bad :) look here for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528181/update-multiple-rows-with-one-query

Comment: I don'T see a question... have you tried any of the options ? what did not work ? please show some code...

Comment: and as a side note, a for loop with many commands sent to the database but all of them in the same transaction is in theory not too bad either, except for the fact that you do many round trips to the server with small data transfer instead of one with more data... I like the second in general but it's arguable...

Comment: If it is a variable list and can get huge, a loop with a transaction is the way to go for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have gone with the for loop approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the Ids you can build an in clause and do an ExecuteScalar:

update sometable
set status = 'Shipped'
where sometableid in (10,17,19,20,89)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread.

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=638673

It talks about using parameter arrays which may be perfect for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanksk for the replies. I had in mind to do it like the following, I was just concerned with keeping the connection open for so many iterations.

```
using (OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connection))
                {
                    oracleConnection.Open();

                    OracleCommand Command = new OracleCommand();
                    Command.Connection = oracleConnection;
                    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    status = "A";
                    foreach (var memberID in MemberIDs)
                    {
                        sqlStatement = " UPDATE " + " ourdbtable" + " Set userstatus = '" + status + "' WHERE " + "memberid= " + memberID;
                        // command
                        Command.CommandText = sqlStatement;
                        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```