# Mysql performance with multiple update in ONE query

Tags: mysql, performance

I need to update about 100 000 records in MySQL table (with indexes) so this process can take long time. i'm searching solution which will work faster.

I have three solutions but i have no time for speed tests.

Solutions:

1. usual UPDATE with each new record in array loop (bad perfomance)
2. using UPDATE syntax like here [Update multiple rows with one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528181/update-multiple-rows-with-one-query) - can't find any perfomance result
3. using LOAD DATA INFILE with the same value for key field, i guess in this case it will call UPDATE instead UNSERT - i guess should work faster when ever

Do you know which is solution is best.
The one important criteria is execution speed.

Thanks.

Comment: You may find solution here..[link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

- `LOAD DATA INFILE` the fastest way to upsert large amount of data from file;
- second solution is not so bad as you might think. Especially if you can execute something like

  update table
  set
    field = values
  where
    id in (list_of_ids)
- but it would be better to post your update query.