# ActiveRecord - Update single column data of different records in single query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to update following data in one single query?

```
ID             Seq
2               2
1               4
4               1
3               3
```

It would be best if it could be done with rails active records, else with sql query would be perfectly fine too.

Reason for doing so is I have scenario where I need to update a group of ids frequently based on ajax request. I believe having it done in single query is much more optimized.

Comment: It's a proper question. Why the downvote?

Comment: I wasn't the downvote, but when I first read the question it needed improvement.

Comment: No problem. Found the answer for my own question. Will post shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution I want from [here](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528181/update-multiple-rows-with-one-query).

This is how I do it with active records.

```
_params = ["12", "9", "13", "14", "15", "16"]
db = ActiveRecord::Base.connection();

query = "UPDATE #{self.table_name} SET display_order = CASE id "       
_params.each_with_index do |d,i|
  query += sanitize_sql(["WHEN ? THEN ? ",d,i])
end

query += "END "
query += "WHERE id in ('#{_params.join("','")}') "
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're asking whether you can complete set of updates in a single transaction.

In rails, you can use [ActiveRecord::Base.transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) for this purpose. For example, for a `Model`, you can:

```
Model.transaction do
  Model.update(2, {:seq => 2} )
  Model.update(1, {:seq => 4} )
  Model.update(4, {:seq => 1} )
  Model.update(3, {:seq => 3} )
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It definitely one of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

We can not directly call multiple updates in a single query using Active Record. As you said we can run it as a sql query in rails.

```
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection();

sql.execute("INSERT into products (id,name,description) VALUES (id-1,'name4','desc4'),(id-2,'name5','desc5'),(id-3,'name6','desc7') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name),description=VALUES(description);")
```