# Insert PHP Array Into MySQL With WHERE Clause

Tags: php, mysql

I've already read [Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause) which is basically what I am doing, but with strings instead of integers. I am having an issue with the WHERE clause.

```
$codes_imp = "'" . implode("','", $codes) . "'";
$passwords_imp = "'" . implode("','", $passwords) . "'";
$comments_imp = "'" . implode("','", $comments) . "'";

$set_pass_query = "INSERT INTO users (password, comments) VALUES ($passwords_imp, $comments_imp) WHERE Code IN ($codes_imp)";
```

When executed, the query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (password, comments) 
VALUES ('password1', 'password2', 'password3', 'comment1', 'comment2', 'comment3') 
WHERE Code IN ('code1', 'code2', 'code3')
```

All columns in the table are of type `VARCHAR`. Clearly I have a syntax error (as it is telling me), but I am not sure how to construct this properly.

Comment: Try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query). This discussion should answer your question.

Comment: Someone needs to read up on [SQL injection handling](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE` and not `INSERT`, to alter existing db rows.
You could use a loop construct like the `foreach` loop.
E.g:

```
foreach($codes_imp as $key=>$code){
   $query="UPDATE users SET password='$passwords_imp[$key]', comments='$comments_imp[$key]' WHERE Code='$code'"
   [Code to execute the query goes here]
}
```

***N.B:*** We need to use a loop construct because `UPDATE` queries can run only on one db row at a time.

***Alternative method:***

Instead of using loops you could use the `CASE WHEN ELSE END` syntax in Mysql.
To know how to use this, please refer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2528188/749232
- http://www.kavoir.com/2009/05/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-one-single-query.html

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this will (for this example) run 3 queries. I wanted to avoid running queries in a loop as it is inefficient and in reality, this code will be updating some 13,000 rows. I used 3 here for a simple example.

Comment: @Kevin_TA, An update query can run only on one row at a time.

Comment: Ahhh. I was not aware of that. Bummer. Ok well thanks for the help.

Comment: I have added an alternative method that might be of interest to you.

Comment: You're welcome @Kevin_TA. If this solved the problem for you, please don't forget to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to constrain an `INSERT` query with a `WHERE` clause. That's a big no-no.

Either you want to `UPDATE`, or you need to drop the `WHERE`

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Right, UPDATE. Sorry, it's been a while since I've done much mysql. I'm trying to add passwords from an array to existing entries in a database.

Comment: Even then, your query doesn't add up. You have 2 fields, and then 6 values and 3 constraints. Can you do a `describe users` and post the output so I can get a better idea?

Comment: @sixeightzero, The scenario seems fine, now that we know he wants to update. Added a possible answer for that.

Comment: I am just trying to update the password and comment of a user with Code = 'code1'. So 'password1' and 'comment1' will be assigned to columns `password` and `comments` respectively. The same would be done for the user with Code = 'code2' and the user with Code = 'code3'.

Comment: @Kevin_TA, I have added  the answer for you.