# PDO bind param in update query

Tags: php, database, pdo

I try to make prepared statament using pdo. It is possible to put several updates atonce?

Ex:

```
    sql1 = "Update product set large = '1large' where id = 1";
    sql2 = "Update product set large = '2large' where id = 2";
    sql3 = "Update product set large = '3large' where id = 3";
```

How to prepare sql1,sql2....sqlN in Pdo to execute faster?
 I found an example but it works line by line (sql1, sql2 ....)

```
 <?php
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE product SET large = ':large'  WHERE id = ':id'");
   $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt->bindParam(':large', $large, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt->execute();
 ?>
```

Comment: yes. get your self *any* tutorial on PDO and try to follow example code

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the 'id' for the value of 'large'.  If the 'id' and 'large' have the same value, why do you need a 'large' field?

Comment: This is different values. I would like to bind sql1 sql2 sql3 in one prepared statment and then execute 3 sql's atonce

Comment: you have to prepare ONLY ONE query $sql1 and then run execute in a loop

Answer (score -1):

Unlike inserts, which can be grouped into a single statement, updates are specific to an existing entry in the database.

Dependant on the broader context of what you are doing you may find a question like this of interest for bulk updates using CASE, WHEN, THEN:

Question: [Update multiple rows with one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528181/update-multiple-rows-with-one-query)