# Filter a model with a list and then set another field with another list

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following Django model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    idNum = models.charField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    idType = models.charField(max_length=10)
```

And I have two lists: `idNums` and `idTypes` (with the same length):

```
idNums = ['1', '3', '5', '7', ...]
idTypes = ['1', '1', '0', '2', '2', ...]
```

I would like to filter `Profile` according to `idNums` and set the corresponding field values with `idTypes`.

The obvious way is:

```
for idNum, idTypes in zip(idNums, idTypes):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(idNum=idNum)
    profile.active = True
    profile.idType = idType
    profile.save()
```

Is this OK? I mean, if there are thousands of profile instances to process, would it take a long time?

Is there is a faster way? What I can think of is, for example, get the list of instance first:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(idNum__in=idNums)
```

Then what?

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, reduce the number of sql `select` queries by using `filter` instead of individual `get` calls, although I believe you would be better off using `in_bulk`. But you will still have to make individual `save` calls:

```
# This will give you a dictionary like {profile_id: Profile, ...}
profile_dict = Profiles.objects.in_bulk(idNums)
for idNum, idTypes in zip(idNums, idTypes):
    profile = profile_dict[idNum]
    profile.active = True
    profile.idType = idType
    profile.save()
```

However, if you can think of some king of primitive functional dependency of idType on idNum, or if you can retreive it from other source in database, you could potentially make use of [`F expressions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) in conjunction with [`.update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update):

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(idNum__in=idNums)
profiles.update(active=True, idType=F('some_column'))
```

Comment: `idType` has nothing to do with `idNum` and they are obtained from a file uploaded by the user. In that case, what opportunity do I have to speed up the process? Thanks.

Comment: If that is the case, I can't think of anything other than the first solution I proposed (with `for` loop).

Comment: Another possible solution: if performance is really critical and you are not afraid of raw SQL, you may try something along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2528188/4904093. Of course, you would have to manually construct the query with python code.